# Threshold alert for Crashlytics

Tags: android, alert, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am looking for a way to put a threshold alert for non-fatal error in Crashlytics. Something like: if a non-fatal error get to a certain amount in 30 60 minutes, then we could receive an email or alert about the event. I know we have velocity alert for fatal error. Do you know any way                               to get it or any solution to archive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently add alerting thresholds for non-fatal errors in Crashlytics.

Comment: Yea, that is sad. I also got reply from Fabric/Firebase team about that. Not available now.